# Python Pytz US/Pacific timezone issue

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

Here's my Python code:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
now_local = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=tz)
print("now_local: {}".format(now_local))
```

It prints this output:

```
now_local: 2018-11-13 12:06:03.255983-07:53
```

which is odd because I believe the timezone offset should be `-08:00` instead of `-07:53`. I'm pretty sure that the timezone offset of US Pacific is 8 hours.

Am I missing something?

I'm on Python version 2.7.14 and Pytz version 2018.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the homepage of `pytz` calls out this error:

> Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors “does not work” with pytz for many timezones.
>
> ```
> >>> datetime(2002, 10, 27, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=amsterdam).strftime(fmt)  # /!\ Does not work this way!
> '2002-10-27 12:00:00 LMT+0020'
> ```

You need to use `tz.localize(dt)`:

```
>>> print(tz.localize(datetime.now()))
2018-11-13 15:20:12.172381-08:00
```

Otherwise your tzinfo object is stuck in the "default", which for most zones is some approximation of "Local Mean Time", not any standard time.